# bind_param Failing But Echo the bind_results return what I want?

Tags: php, mysqli

Error Messages Present:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/New/API/Constants.php on line 22

**Updated with entire constants.php**
Here is my code on constants.php:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['real_name']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['real_name'];

    $InnerJoinQuery = $STD->prepare("
    SELECT Users.ID, Users.Password, UserInformation.LastName, UserInformation.Firstname, UserInformation.DOB
    FROM Users
    INNER JOIN UserInformation
    ON Users.ID = UserInformation.UserID WHERE Users.Username = ?");
    $InnerJoinQuery->bind_param("s", $username);
    $InnerJoinQuery->execute();
    $InnerJoinQuery->bind_result($UID, $Password, $LastName, $Firstname, $DOB);
    $InnerJoinQuery->fetch();

    $_SESSION['UID'] = $UID;
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $Password;
    $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $LastName;
    $_SESSION['LastName'] = $Firstname;
    $_SESSION['DOB'] = $DOB;
}

    echo $UID."<br>".$Password."<br>".$LastName."<br>".$Firstname."<br>".$DOB;
```

But:

```
echo $UID."<br>".$Password."<br>".$LastName."<br>".$Firstname."<br>".$DOB;
```

*Returns;*

> 5 
>   xxx
>   Gill
>   Daryl
>   211094

*also:*

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

> Array ( [real_name] => InhumaneSlayer [Password] => xxx [UID] =>
>   5 [Firstname] => Gill [LastName] => Daryl [DOB] => 211094 )

Th above is expected output

Which is expected? So bind_param is failing but bind_results is gathering the right information?

Comment: IF that is line 22, there must be other lines above this. Can you plaese post them. it would seem that the problem is probably there.

Comment: Updated with the entire constants.php

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors here `@session_start()`?

Comment: @PeeHaa They was generating warnings, but it has been sorted out a while ago. Never got round to unsupress the errors; Just done it and no errors was generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your full page, how are you getting `$STD` which I presume is your connection variable.

if you are including the database and this page from a different page.... **include your database file.**

Change:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['real_name']))
{
```

To:

```
include "YourFile";
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['real_name']))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this:

```
    @session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['real_name'];

if (isset($username))
{
```

to this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['real_name']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['real_name'];
```

............

```
$InnerJoinQuery->bind_param("s", $username);
```

Have you checked the session to be sure this is being set. and i think you have first and last name backwards:

```
$_SESSION['UID'] = $UID;
$_SESSION['Password'] = $Password;
$_SESSION['Firstname'] = $LastName;
$_SESSION['LastName'] = $Firstname;
$_SESSION['DOB'] = $DOB;
```

try to echo:

```
echo $_SESSION['UID']."<br/>" ;
echo $_SESSION['Password']."<br/>" ;
echo $_SESSION['Firstname']."<br/>" ;
echo $_SESSION['LastName'] ."<br/>" ;
echo $_SESSION['DOB'] ."<br/>" ;
echo $_SESSION['real_name']."<br/>" ;
```

Comment: The error message is still present, and I have updated my question with the current code i'm using

Comment: Answer to your most recent update is yes, i have print_r($_SESSION); and it has returned the expected results

Comment: Update.. vardump the prepared statement and it's returning a `bool(false)`  but the query seems to work within a $STD->query

Comment: What version of php are you using?